# How do I stop org-babel from trying to edit a source block in a dedicated buffer?

Tags: org-babel

I have org :jupyter in my Doom Emacs init.el, i.e., ob-jupyter, for using Jupyter with org-babel, and there's a really annoying behavior when I'm in an org file, editing a source block that begins with #+BEGIN_SRC jupyter-python :session py. Every time I enter the block by pressing o ("open" a new line for entering text, the Evil command) it disables editing in the source block, saying that the code block is actually being handled by a dedicated buffer ("Not in a sub editing buffer"). It doesn't open a window for the sub-editing buffer, so I have to go hunting for it in my buffer list, and then abort the process with C-c C-k, which is a pain.

The thing is, I never want to edit code blocks in a sub-editing buffer. How can I disable that?

Comment: This (mis)behavior seems to be specific to Doom, so maybe report it to them? Even if you are happy with your answer (which is a bit radical in my view), others might benefit from a fix.

Comment: I use vanilla emacs but this affects me too with my setup.  I had yet to investigate what the culprit is tho.

Comment: I do not remember seeing this issue before upgrading to emacs29 tho.  So likely some changes in emacs that made emacs-jupyter not working well with it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself. I couldn't find an option for this, but doing this seems to work, so far:

```
;; Disable editing source code in dedicated buffer
(defun org-edit-src-code nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in 2023 with emacs29 and for me my workaround now is to disable `electric-indent-mode` and to manually indent.  Which I believe is better than to removing `org-edit-src-code` altogether.

I have also filed this issue: https://github.com/emacs-jupyter/jupyter/issues/488